# why can't load mcrypt for php5 in centos7?

Tags: php, nginx, mcrypt

I have install `php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.16-2.el7` in my centos7. and I can find `mcrypt.ini` in path `/etc/php.d`.

But when I print phpinfo, there is no `mcrypt.ini` in 'Additional .ini files parsed' section.

[image]

I reload nginx already.

You can read my phpinfo here: http://vachanon.com/info.php

Thanks!

Comment: Check your error log? Maybe there's a dependency not getting met. Do you see it when you run `php -m` from CLI?

Comment: @miken32 yes, I can see it in 'php -m'. where the err log in?

Comment: You reloaded nginx, but did you reload php-fpm?